# sum time with specific delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Right now I have a problem with sum time based on specific condition. For example, I have something like this.

[image]

Due to some reason, I have to add the work time based on their activity date if only approval status on the activity date is approve.

So for the restriction example I have something like this

```
-----------------------------------------------
| Activity Date   | ApprovalStatus | WorkTime |
-----------------------------------------------
| 2017-01-06      | Rejected       | 01:00:00 |
-----------------------------------------------
| 2017-01-06      | Approve        | 03:00:00 |
-----------------------------------------------
| 2017-01-06      | Waiting        | 02:00:00 |
-----------------------------------------------
| 2017-01-06      | Approve        | 01:00:00 |
-----------------------------------------------
```

From those example, the accepted worktime that only will be summed from this circumstances, So the expected result is become like below. The expected result is become 04:00:00 since only the approve counted for final result.

```
-----------------------------------------------
| Activity Date   | ApprovalStatus | WorkTime |
-----------------------------------------------
| 2017-01-06      | Approved       | 04:00:00 |
-----------------------------------------------
```

Is there any enlightenment to solve this problem?
PS: I am using SQL Server 2014. Hope you can help me, thank you!!

Comment: summation of only approve status records of the same date??

Comment: yes @Jibin Balachadran , on the same date :)

Comment: What's the datatype of WorkTime?

Comment: it is time type :),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like below

**Schema:**

```
SELECT * INTO #TAB FROM( 
SELECT '2017-01-06' AS Activity_Date 
, 'Rejected' AS ApprovalStatus 
, '01:00:00' AS WorkTime
UNION ALL 
SELECT '2017-01-06' , 'Approve' , '03:00:00' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT '2017-01-06' , 'Waiting' , '02:00:00' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT '2017-01-06' , 'Approve' , '01:00:00' 
)A
```

Now Sum the Hours column by grouping the Date

```
SELECT [Activity_Date]
,CAST(DATEADD(HH,SUM( DATEDIFF(HH,'00:00:00',WorkTime)),'00:00:00') AS TIME(0))
FROM #TAB 
WHERE ApprovalStatus='Approve'
GROUP BY [Activity_Date]
```

Result:

```
+---------------+------------------+
| Activity_Date | (No column name) |
+---------------+------------------+
| 2017-01-06    | 04:00:00         |
+---------------+------------------+
```

**UPDATE :**

The `SUM` function will only take  *exact numeric or approximate numeric data type* . It won't accept date or Time datatype for summation.

It is documented in [SUM (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql) on microsoft website.

> SUM ( [ ALL | DISTINCT ] expression )
>
> *expression*
>
> Is a constant, column, or function, and any combination of
>   arithmetic, bitwise, and string operators. expression is an expression
>   of the **exact numeric or approximate numeric data type** category, except
>   for the bit data type. Aggregate functions and subqueries are not
>   permitted.

So you can only have a chance to write your own logic to get the sum of Time. This below will calculate the SUM of time upto milliseconds.

```
SELECT [Activity_Date]
,CAST(DATEADD(ms, SUM(DATEDIFF(ms, '00:00:00.000', WorkTime)), '00:00:00.000') as time(0)) 
FROM #TAB2 
WHERE ApprovalStatus='Approve'
GROUP BY [Activity_Date]
```

Comment: from your answer, it is almost right. however, i don't know why it cannot handle like 04:00 + 03:30 should be 07:30, but the result from your example is 07:00.

Comment: Now check my update for the info. The updated query work for minutes and seconds too. :) @FarisFajar

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the records by ApprovalStatus and do a summation on worktime by grouping it by activity date.

Use this, if you want to add only the hour part.

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(HH,'00:00:00',WorkTime)) AS [TotalWorktime]
FROM [YourTable]
WHERE ApprovalStatus = 'Approve'
GROUP BY [Activity Date]
```

**OR**

Use this if you want to add even the minutes part.

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'0:00:00',CONVERT(TIME,WorkTime)))/60 + (SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'0:00:00',CONVERT(TIME,WorkTime)))%60)/100.0 AS [TotalWorktime]
FROM [YourTable]
WHERE ApprovalStatus = 'Approve'
GROUP BY [Activity Date]
```

Comment: Operand data type time is invalid for sum operator, i don't know why?

Comment: the return is like 600, 400, 480 :)

Comment: from your first answer, i got it right . how ever, when the sum is like 03:00 + 04:30 , it returns 07:00. i don't know why?

Comment: @FarisFajar If you have to add the minutes part then use the second query.